# Plotting 3D Scatter plots in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am looking for a flutter package to plot a 3D scatter shart given a series of X, Y, Z and R, G, B values. Looking to output something like this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/VtwTxnqHY4ahc24u6

I know [echarts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_echarts) can do 3d scatter plots, but I need it to work on Mobile and Web

Question: does anyone know of a flutter package that I can use to plot 3d scatter charts for mobile and web?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a will there is a way,
I don't know any packages but you can implement it yourself pretty easily:

1: Import the package vector_math64

`import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vm;`

2: Make a projection Matrix.

`vm.Matrix4 perspectiveMatrix = vm.makePerspectiveMatrix(vm.radians(150), 16/9,3, 20);`

3: Make a Vector3 to move your plot, a 3x3 rotation Matrix to rotate your plot and another Vector3 to scale your plot.

```
vm.Vector3 location = vm.Vector3.array([100,-200,300]);

vm.Matrix3 rotation = vm.Matrix3.identity();
rotation.setRotationX(vm.radians(xRot));
rotation.setRotationY(vm.radians(yRot));
rotation.setRotationZ(vm.radians(zRot));

vm.Vector3 scale = vm.Vector3.array([1,1,1]);
```

4: With these, make a projection matrix from your local coordinate system to the world coordinate system

`vm.Matrix4 localToWorldMatrix = Matrix4.compose(location, vm.Quaternion.fromRotation(rotation), scale);`

5: Your final projection Matrix will be:

`vm.Matrix4 finalMatrix = perspectiveMatrix*localToWorldMatrix;`

6: If you change rotation recalculate matrix before every paint/update

7: Make a CustomPainter

8: Save your list of points as vm.Vector3's

`List<vm.Vector3> points = [...]`

9: Inside your update function: Copy all your points with vector.clone(), apply the projection and put them into another list

```
List<vm.Vector3> cloneList = [];
points.forEach((element) { 
  vm.Vector3 clone = element.clone();
  clone.applyProjection(finalMatrix);
  cloneList.add(clone);
});
```

10: Inside your draw function draw the points:

```
cloneList.forEach((element) {   
  canvas.drawCircle(Offset(element.storage[0]*size.width,element.storage[1]
  *size.height), 1, Paint()..color = Colors.red);
});
```

11: Make 4 points for your coordinate system: (0,0,0),(10,0,0),(0,10,0),(0,0,10).

12: Apply projection to the 4 points for your coordinate system, draw lines, and your good to go